Using Boost::Compute, how do I pass two values to a custom function?
I'd like to use Boost::Compute to do a calculation using two passed in values.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10.  I'm using vcpkg to pull in OpenCL and Boost::Compute.
Here is the code I have:
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/compute/core.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/container/vector.hpp>

std::mt19937 rng{ std::random_device()() };
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1);

namespace compute = boost::compute;
using namespace boost::compute::lambda;

int GetRandomNumber()
{
    return dist(rng);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const auto device = compute::system::default_device();
    const compute::context context(device);
    compute::command_queue commandQueue(context, device);

    std::vector<int> hostVector1(10000);
    std::vector<int> hostVector2(10000);
    std::vector<int> hostResultVector(10000);
    std::ranges::generate(hostVector1, GetRandomNumber);
    std::ranges::generate(hostVector2, GetRandomNumber);

    compute::vector<int> deviceVector1(hostVector1.size(), context);
    compute::vector<int> deviceVector2(hostVector2.size(), context);
    compute::vector<int> deviceResultVector(hostResultVector.size(), context);

    compute::copy(hostVector1.begin(), hostVector1.end(), deviceVector1.begin(), commandQueue);
    compute::copy(hostVector2.begin(), hostVector2.end(), deviceVector2.begin(), commandQueue);

    transform(deviceVector1.begin(), deviceVector1.end(), deviceVector2.begin(), deviceResultVector.begin(), _1 * _2, commandQueue);

    compute::copy(deviceResultVector.begin(), deviceResultVector.end(), hostResultVector.begin(), commandQueue);

    return 0;
}

When I try to build, I get this error:
1>C:\Users\Dave\source\repos\BoostComputeTest\BoostComputeTest\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\x64-windows\include\boost\compute\iterator\transform_iterator.hpp(177,53): error C2039: 'get_buffer': is not a member of 'boost::compute::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<boost::compute::buffer_iterator<T>,boost::compute::buffer_iterator<T>,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>'
1>C:\Users\Dave\source\repos\BoostComputeTest\BoostComputeTest\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\x64-windows\include\boost\compute\iterator\transform_iterator.hpp(177,53): error C2039:         with
1>C:\Users\Dave\source\repos\BoostComputeTest\BoostComputeTest\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\x64-windows\include\boost\compute\iterator\transform_iterator.hpp(177,53): error C2039:         [
1>C:\Users\Dave\source\repos\BoostComputeTest\BoostComputeTest\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\x64-windows\include\boost\compute\iterator\transform_iterator.hpp(177,53): error C2039:             T=int
1>C:\Users\Dave\source\repos\BoostComputeTest\BoostComputeTest\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\x64-windows\include\boost\compute\iterator\transform_iterator.hpp(177,53): error C2039:         ]
1>(compiling source file 'Main.cpp')
1>    C:\Users\Dave\source\repos\BoostComputeTest\BoostComputeTest\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\x64-windows\include\boost\compute\iterator\zip_iterator.hpp(172,7):

Is there a problem with my code, or should I report this as a bug to the Boost project?

It's not an issue on my platform (Ubuntu 24.04). Did you have the relevant includes? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82d55a5676eb224c

@sehe, I updated the code snippet to add the includes.

Yeah, no issue compiling on my system (it doesn't run, but that might be my graphics config).

I just tried it on Arch Linux and it worked as expected.
